# How to Display '0 Results' Message in st_aggrid with Streamlit When Data is Filtered

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I'm attempting to implement a function that utilizes st_aggrid to display data in a Streamlit app.

My current issue is that I am unable to display a `0 Results` message when there is no data visible after applying filters. I would like this message to be shown within the table, possibly in the center or a corner, as demonstrated in the image below.

[image]

This is my code for now:

```python
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder, GridUpdateMode, DataReturnMode, JsCode
import pandas as pd

def ag_grid_df_with_filters(df: pd.DataFrame, column_configs: dict = {}) -> None:
    """
    Show a dataframe in a ag-grid with filters and column configs.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): dataframe to show
        column_configs (dict): column configs for ag-grid
            example:
                {
                    "Published": {"type": ["timedeltaFormat"]},
                    "Funding Amount": {
                        "type": ["numericColumn", "numberColumnFilter"],
                        "cellRenderer": some_java_script_code_string
                    },
                    "Website": {
                        "cellRenderer": some_java_script_code_string
                    },
                }
            note:
                this function accepts only cellRenderer and type for now
                if something else is needed add it below in column configuration
                part
    """
    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)

    ########################
    # Column configuration #
    ########################
    if column_configs:
        for column_name, config in column_configs.items():
            column_options = {}

            # for now we are using just cellRenderer and type
            # if something else is needed add it here:
            if "type" in config:
                column_options["type"] = config["type"]

            if "cellRenderer" in config:
                column_options["cellRenderer"] = JsCode(config["cellRenderer"])

            gb.configure_column(column_name, **column_options)

    ######################
    # Grid configuration #
    ######################
    gb.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", use_checkbox=False)
    gb.configure_side_bar()
    gridoptions = gb.build()

    AgGrid(
        df,
        height=600,
        gridOptions=gridoptions,
        enable_enterprise_modules=True,
        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED,
        data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.FILTERED_AND_SORTED,
        fit_columns_on_grid_load=False,
        allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
    )
```

Comment: Try to search in aggrid if such feature is available. If not just use st.info('Sorry no data') or something to inform the users that the result has no entries.